# ToString() Dropdown

Tags: javascript

im creating dependent dropdown whereby when a user select the id then the employee's name appear automatically. but right now the dropdown cannot accept the number. only accept string. how can i fix this? thank you in advance. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9DbZ.png)

```js
 function addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(el,arrayOfArrays,index){
       var currentlyAdded = [];
       el.innerHTML = '<option></option>';
      arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
        if(currentlyAdded.indexOf(r[index].toString()) === -1){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = r[index];
        el.appendChild(option);
        currentlyAdded.push(r[index]);
        }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the selected value to a string before comparing it with the values in the currentlyAdded array. You can use the toString() method to do this. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
function addUniqueOptionsToDropdownList(el, arrayOfArrays, index) {
  var currentlyAdded = [];
  el.innerHTML = '<option></option>';
  arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
    if (currentlyAdded.indexOf(r[index].toString()) === -1) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent = r[index];
      el.appendChild(option);
      currentlyAdded.push(r[index].toString());
    }
  });
}
```

This way, even if the selected value is a number, it will be converted to a string before comparing it, ensuring that only unique values are added to the dropdown list.